# Creating application for iOS 4.1 With XCODE Version 4.3.2 (4E2002)

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, xcode, ipad

(^.^)"Hi again sorry for my English is not good if someone like correct my redaction I would appreciate this"

Hi I have the next issue I want to create one project for iOS 4.1 ++ and in Xcode I do this

- File
- New
- Project
- Single View Applications
- etc.

And in Deployment Target I choose 4.1 **But if I see the main.m have one @autoreleasepool but in iOS 4.1 this not exist** How can I fix it.

Thanks very much.

Comment: i cant understand your question. explain ur problem...

Comment: Never edit the main.m if you're making a iOS/Mac app.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using this instead.

```
NSAutoreleasePool *pool = [[NSAutoreleasePool alloc] init];
return UIApplicationMain(argc, argv, nil, NSStringFromClass([AppDelegate class]));
[pool drain];
```

Also read [this article](http://iphonedevelopertips.com/xcode/base-sdk-and-iphone-os-deployment-target-developing-apps-with-the-4-x-sdk-deploying-to-3-x-devices.html), it's about deploying 4.x to 3.x, but I think you should be able to solve your problem accordingly.